# Arguments of methods

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to figure out one thing about generics.
If I declare a method like

```java
public <T> List<T> toList(final T... arr) { ... }
```

Can I return both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`?
Or for example, if I have declare a method like

```
public <T> T[] toArray(final List<T> l) { ... }
```

Can I pass both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` as argument and it'll works good?

 If this is right, does it works with all objects too? So, if I create a class and I extend it more times, can I use the top class as arg of method, but the pass its subclasses when I call it?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. Has NOTHING to do with generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about *g*enerics only. You can assign any object to a variable of its parent class.

```
Object o = 5;    // It's valid
```

If you pass a `LinkedList` or `ArrayList` to the `toArray()`method, it doesn't matter. It will be automatically converted to `List`. Similarly, if you return a `LinkedList` from the `toArray()` method, it doesn't matter. It will be converted to `List.`

But one thing to keep in mind is if you pass a `LinkedList`, it will get converted to `List` and you will be able to use only the methods of the `List` interface.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.addFirst(1);              // Invalid
```

Comment: It's not converted, it works because an ArrayList (and a LinkedList) IS a List.

Comment: Yes LInkedList is a List because it implements List, but LinkedList is implicitly casted to List and the methods such as addFirst(), offer() will not work if it is assigned to a List variable